# Why do we use alpha-cut for arithmetic operations with fuzzy numbers?

Tags: fuzzy-set

I just started studying fuzzy sets. In the context of fuzzy numbers, I saw the arithmetic operations are defined with respect to alpha-cut (For example see [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjS-cDdyfCBAxWzT6QEHV03Ca0QFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FMohamed-Mourad-Lafifi%2Fpost%2FUsing_membership_function_trimf_for_a_single_degree_of_freedom_system%2Fattachment%2F6139c4ec647f3906fc9732eb%2FAS%253A1066043212566528%25401631175916350%2Fdownload%2FFuzzyArithmeticwithandwithoutusing-cutmethod_AComparativeStudy.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0s2cuKteN9VyPSNGTBHK_u&opi=89978449)). But I don't know why alpha-cut is so important for such operations and why it is implied a lot? For example, isn't it possible to define these operations without using alpha-cut?